# Validating multiple elements using each

Tags: javascript, loops, each, cypress

So I have a list basically with one icon and I have to run a loop and check that the icon is present or not. For that the below code works like a charm -

```
cy.get('span.test').each((element) => {
    cy.wrap(element).find('i').should('have.attr', 'data-icon-name', 'Archive')
});
```

The problem arises when the same list items has two icons, then as per above it just checks the first icon which is not archive and fails. How can I make sure that in the conditions where there are multiple icons it should check for the other blocks as well till it finds the Archived icon.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are hardcoding your check with "Archive". You are already looping through the elements using find, you can instead loop through the elements and get their attribute value and perform operations you may need.

```
 cy.get('span.test').each((element) => {
  // this will give you all the data-icon-name attribute values, in your example it will print - LockSolid Archived
  // now you can match the value and do any operations e.g. if(element.getAttribute("data-icon-name") == "Archive") alert("Archive found")
  console.log(element.getAttribute("data-icon-name"));
 });
```

If there is no "data-icon-name" attribute present, it will give a null value.

Comment: Hey @Ank Thanks for the answer. but unfortunately `element.getAttribute` is not a valid function, but however your answer helped be to think differently. This time instead of `span.test`, I iterated directly through the Archived icon `span.test > i[data-icon-name="Archive"]` and it solved the problem. And then I just validated that the element is visible or not using `expect(element).to.be.visible`

Comment: Glad you figured it out :)